# attempt to index nil with 'value' when 'nil' is previously defined - lua

Tags: indexing, lua, null, roblox

script > button > screengui > startergui
on line 3 i define the variable 'votes' and on line 6 i assign it a value. when i call that value in line 10 to preform arithmetic, it produces an error
'votes' is an integer value.

i am trying to create a voting system where each vote increases a value within a player's leaderstats to indicate how many votes that player has.

script:

```
local button = script.Parent
local leaderstats
local votes
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    leaderstats = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
    votes = leaderstats:WaitForChild("Votes")       
end)

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
votes.Value += 1
end)
```

Comment: And you are sure that PlayerAdded finishes first? Especially when Votes does not exist it will wait forever.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `MouseButton1Down` event is firing before the `PlayerAdded` event initializes the `votes` variable.

Lucky for you, you shouldn't need to use the `PlayerAdded` event to define the `votes` variable. The NumberValue already exists, you just need to find it properly.

Assuming that you have a Script somewhere that creates your leaderstats for you when you join the game, it is likely that this LocalScript will execute after it. So just access the values that already exist on your `Player` object.

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local button = script.Parent
local leaderstats = Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
local votes = leaderstats.Votes

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    votes.Value += 1
end)
```

Be aware that any changes you make to this `Votes` value will only show up for you. Other players won't see these changes. If you want other players to see these changes, you'll need to use a RemoteEvent to communicate to the server, and have the server Script make the change to the `Votes.Value`.